# Use mooFX with jQuery

Tags: jquery

jQuery animations are choppy for me (specially in firefox). So i've decided to use [MoofX](http://moofx.mad4milk.net/)
for animations. The moofx site gives no clear explanation of how to implement the code

How to implement Moofx effects on this code (basically replac the jquery animations with moofx)

```
jQuery(this).slideDown();
```

I don't want a toggle function. Also, It would be nice if the code was kept bit similar to the current code.

Comment: A google search reveals a bunch of helpful info on moo.fx.  Here's one: http://www.avinashv.net/tutorials/moofx/.  This makes it look like it's based on the prototype.js or mootools.js framework so you need that too.

Comment: The page itself says that it's outdated and it's not what i'm particularly looking for

Comment: Are you aware of ANY documentation that says MoofX works with jQuery as a replacement for jQuery animations?  I just see doc that says it works with prototype.js or mootools.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for but, you can override jQuery functions in an anonymous function. Here's a sample overriding the `fadeIn` function:

```
(function(){
    // storing the reference to the original function 
    var original = jQuery.fn.fadeIn;

    // this is the actual override/replacement
    // it has to happen before you start up jQuery
    jQuery.fn.fadeIn= function(){

        // do whatever you wanna do here instead of using the original function
        // I'm not super familiar with mooFX, but I take it's similar to MooTools

        // This line can be entirely removed, leaving only YOUR code, in this case 
        // the MooFX effect replacing the fadeIn. If you leave it, it will run both
        // your code and the original code
        original.apply( this, arguments );
    }
})();

// start up jQuery
$(function() {
    // and code here like normal, meaning, 
    // every time you call $('#something').fadeIn({..}), it will run your code
});
```

**Note**: Again, not sure if this is what you're looking for and I'm not sure how MooFX plays out along with jQuery. The code above is simply to show how to override a jQuery function.